# Why is the syllable division in "experience" different from its pronunciation

Tags: orthography

Why is the syllable division in the word "experience" ex-pe-ri-ence, and not ex-per-i-ence?

Comment: Because the rules of dividing written words into "syllables" only apply to letters, not to real syllables with real sounds. English spelling does not represent English pronunciation in a regular way. Sorry about that, but it's the truth. English spelling is good for Middle English, but it sucks for Modern English.

Answer (score 4):

Because when Webster first came up with the system of dividing words into syllables, *experience* was pronounced *ex-pee-ri-ence* and not *ex-peer-i-ence*, the way many of us do today. And they haven't bothered changing it since.

From [Webster's 1892 dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=J9EVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP3&dq=dictionary+webster%27s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiujYvXsYjSAhXJ6YMKHSr2BXsQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=eve&f=false):

> Experience: (ĕks-pē′rĭ-*e*ns) — /ɛksˈpiː.rɪ.əns/.
>   Experiment: (ĕks-pĕr′ĭ-m*e*nt) — /ɛksˈpɛr.ɪ.mənt/.

I've translated Webster's notation into IPA, as nobody uses their 1892 phonetic notation anymore.

The [*American Heritage Dictionary's*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=experience) syllabifications are quite strange. They have:

> ex·pe·ri·ence,
>   ex·per·i·enced,
>   ex·per·i·enc·ing,
>   ex·per·i·enc·es.

I would guess they kept the original syllabification of *experience* for the sake of consistency, but they have updated all the inflections of the word to match the current pronunciation.

Comment: I'm having a hard time producing contrasting pronunciations of *experiment* where there’s an open /piː/ syllable in one and a closed /piːr/ one in the other. Shouldn’t tense vowels be open syllables, checked ones closed? That said, there are definitely East Coast folks who pronounce this word differently than I do. They seem to strangely say “eggzbeeramint” — which sounds more like a failed hangover concoction of “eggs, beer, and mint” than it does the word I’m familiar with. I think I have a tense /per/ rather than lax /pɛr/, and I know I don’t have /piːr/.

Comment: @tchrist: right: the difference between *mirror* and *nearer* disappeared in most American English accents a long time ago. *Experience* used to have the *nearer* vowel rather than the *mirror* vowel, which is why it was syllabified the way it was. (And I can't tell you exactly how *nearer* was pronounced in 1892.)

Comment: I don't believe I ***ever*** have a lax vowel before /r/, whether in *marry–merry–Mary*, *mirror–nearer*, or *horse–hoarse*. Of those, only that first triplet can I easily perceive and produce the non-merged version of; the others I’m hazy on. I perceive my own production of all those [before /r/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/) as [**tense monophthongs** (so /er/, /ir/, /or/)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_vowels#Tense.E2.80.93lax_neutralization), which is originally from the eastern Wisconsin–Illinois border.

Comment: The real pronunciation of _experience_ in American English syllabifies into /ɛk.spi.ri.əns/. The fact that the letter X represents a consonant cluster /ks/, and that the actual syllable boundary falls between the /k/ and the /s/ makes any syllabification scheme involving the letter X unsatisfactory. That's what I meant in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you assume ex-pe-ri-ence is wrong?  That is how I say it. Therein lies the answer to  your question. Because of different dialects and regional variances, **there is no one true syllable division**. Lexicographers basically choose the pronunciation they believe to be most common. They are usually correct, and their guidance is helpful. But 5 years from the dictionary's release, pronunciation may well have changed.

English is defined from the ground up. There is no governing body to declare standards. English educators, style guides, grammarians, lexicographers, etc., do their best atop constantly shifting sands.

Comment: Not 5 years from the dictionary's release ... more like 125 years from the dictionary's release. Webster hasn't changed most of their syllabifications for over a century.

Comment: @PeterShor It seems I was unclear. My point was that the language keeps changing while the book sits on its shelf.  I'll edit that part for clarity.